# Back to History not working properly

Tags: javascript, php

I have page with cart in which items are added and on clicking `Place Order` button Customer is landed to checkout page 1. Then after filling email on Page1 as Guest, he is redirected to Page 2.

On page 2 i have button like

```
 <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</a>
```

On Clicking Go back button, the page appearing is the page having cart. In Nutshell, no checkout page is being shown to user on clicking Go Back button.

I am using PHP header on cart page as below:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');
```

Is this causing the issue?
I tried removing this header but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript: history.go(-1) behaves like the browser back button, which can yield unexpected results during a checkout.

I'd recommend changing your Go Back link to the actual URL of your checkout page.

```
<a href="yourcheckoutpage.php" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</a>
```

Comment: By using your approach, it will not be feasible as previous page has POST values...

Comment: You can set your previous page to run with or without the POST values. When you get POST values save them to session, and when you don't get them, try to retrieve them from session.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"
```